# Well-ordered and Inductive Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image: question]

The above is exercise 3.17 from Goldrei's "Classic Set Theory."

Here, inductive means that if $A\subseteq X$, $0\in A$, and if $A$ is closed under the $^+$ operation, then $A=X$.

I'm aware of the usual proof that shows a set being well-ordered implies the induction principle, but here, the proof doesn't seem to go through:

Suppose, for contradiction, that $A\ne X$. Then the complement of $A$, $A^C$, is non-empty, and by assumption has a least element $s$. This least element cannot be $0$ because that is in $A$.

Here is the problem: we need a $t\in X$ such that $t^+=s$, so that we can observe that $t\in A$ (otherwise, $t<s$ would be the least element of $A^C$). Then, by definition of $A$, we can conclude that $t^+ = s\in A$, contradicting the fact that $s$ is the least element of $A^C$.

How do I show that there is such a $t\in X$? In the case of the $X = \mathbb{N}$, $^+$ is the successor function, and the fact that every natural number except zero is the successor of some number is proved using induction, which we cannot do here because the induction principle is what we're trying to prove!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With that definition of inductive, I don't think this is true. What about $X=\{0,1\}\times\mathbb N$ with $(x_1,y_1)\leq (x_2,y_2)$ iff $x_1<x_2$ or ($x_1=x_2$ and $y_1\leq y_2$.) This is a well order, on $X$ and $(x,y)^{+}=(x,y+1)$.  But $A=\{0\}\times \mathbb N$ contains the least element $(0,0)$ and is closed under ${}^+$. In this case, the least element $(1,0)$ not in $A$ has no solution to $t^{+}=(1,0)$.

Comment: It seems like an incorrect question to me too. For example, $\{0, 1, \ldots, \omega, \omega+1, \ldots\}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: I see; it does appear to be an incorrect question. Thanks for the counterexamples!

Comment: Are you sure about that definition of "inductive", and can you give an exact quote if so? This answer gives a contradictory definition of an inductive set, which is supposedly from the same textbook: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/792929/13524

Comment: It's a slightly weird definition - when Goldrei defines inductive set, it is only for $x^+=x\cup\{x\}$, and all it says $X$ is inductive if $\emptyset\in X$ and if $x\in X$ implies $x^+=x\cup\{x\}\in X$. So this problem has to be assuming some other definition, since nothing about the conditions ensures that $\emptyset\in X$, and $x^+$ is defined differently. But it is also odd to ask you to prove the obvious translation, since the question has already done so....

Comment: You might be able to show that $(X,\leq)$ is isomorphic to some $(Y,\subseteq)$ where $Y$ is an inductive set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong definition of inductive, and with your definition, the question is wrong.

The book is specific in the definition of inductive set:

[image]

and the next page:

[image]

So the problem is very odd, unless there are other definitions between, because $X$ is not (necessarily) inductive in this definition, since nothing requires $\emptyset\in X$.

There is a way to define an inductive set $Y$ so that $(Y,\subseteq,{}^+)$ is isomorphic to $(X,\leq,{}^+)$, but I think that will need transfinite induction.